# Saving values of html selects and re-select them on postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have five dropdownlists in form of html selects. The first binds at page load using jQuery, and the rest bind when the previous dropdown has been selected. I also have five hidden fields for each dropdown which stores the selected values.

My problem is that when I do a post back, i.e. click the "Search" button, I have to re-populate the dropdowns and select the correct values again by using the ID's in the hidden fields. So far, I've come up with no good way to do this.

In the .aspx page:

```
<select name="boxFunktionsnedsattning" id="boxFunktionsnedsattning" multiple="multiple </select>

<asp:TextBox ID="HiddenBoxFunktionsnedsattning" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function boxFunktionsnedsattningPopulate() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Sok.aspx/getFunktionsnedsattningar",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: LoadBoxFunktionsnedsattning,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });

}

//============================================================================================================

function LoadBoxFunktionsnedsattning(response) {

    var result = response.d;

    var options = $("#boxFunktionsnedsattning");
    options.text(''); // clear the box content before reloading
    if ($('#boxFunktionsnedsattning').val != '') {
        options.removeAttr("disabled");
        options.multipleSelect("enable");
    }
    else {
        options.attr("disabled", true);
        options.multipleSelect("disable");
    }

    $.each(result, function () {
        options.append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));
    });
    UpdateBoxEnabledState();
    options.multipleSelect("refresh");

}
</script>
```

Backend code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static Funktionsnedsattning[] getFunktionsnedsattningar()
    {
        GetDataService.IgetDataClient gdc = new IgetDataClient();
        return gdc.getFunktionsnedsattningAll();
    }
```

I should add that I'm a beginner when it comes to jQuery, so there is probably something I've overlooked.

Comment: do on the dropdown's viewstate.

Comment: How would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

IF your using webforms use an onclick function to post back to the server instead of a submit. I think this is the functionality you want because the variables in the inputs of the form will keep its value. Is the search button returning results on the same page or a different one because it will determine the ease in which you can keep varibles during a post back. Good luck!

Comment: Hi! Yes, the search button returns the result on the same page in a repeater. So if I understood correctly, the onClick event function should not be in the backend code but as a javascript function on the aspx page?

Comment: Nope the on click will be attached to asp button tag and reference a corresponding function in your code behind file

Comment: The easist way is to achieve this is to double click asp button when in visual studios design view

Comment: Ok, this is what my button looks like right now:


<asp:Button ID="FreeTextSearchButton" runat="server" onClick="FreeTextSearchButton_Click" Text="Search" CssClass="btn"/>

The function in my code behind calls another function which processes the information from the dropdowns and returns objects after making a SQL query. These objects are then bound to the repeater on my search page, and results in a postback.

Comment: Throw a literal on page and return the result in the literal. Yeah it is a post back, asp.net is just carrying the information over for you. In your function just return a string so you can see it will keep your drop downs do not redirect the response

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, but I did as you said and the result is still a postback.

Comment: Add if post back and do not bind the dropdowns onload

Comment: They are being rebinded onload :) you only want it to occurs when it is not posting back to the server

Comment: Only the first dropdown (html select) is bound when the page loads, and it's done with jQuery client side. The rest of the selects bind when when the user picks something from the list, so basically each select activates the next one and so on. The only things in the code behind are the get functions and the onclick event for the search button, everything else is in the aspx page with jQuery.

Comment: If that the case you will have to rebind with jquery you could return values to an empty hidden input and reattach all of them. What a pain :(

Comment: Yeah, a real pain in the ***. I have a HiddenField for each select which stores the value of the selected items, and I finally got it working. Posting the solution below. It was actually a pretty easy solution, don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the following solution:

```
function fillFunktionsnedsattning() {

         //stores the value of selected items

         var $fn = $('#<%=HiddenBoxFunktionsnedsattning.ClientID%>'); 

         //creates an array of the values in the hidden field

         var fnSplit = $fn.val().split(",");

         //val() accepts an array which it uses to select items in the list (go figure)

         $("#boxFunktionsnedsattning").val(fnSplit);
         $("#boxFunktionsnedsattning").multipleSelect("refresh");

         //function that triggers the binding of the next dropdown
         boxFunktionsnedsattningOnChange();

     }
```

For it to work, this function needs to be called in the function that populates the dropdown. Each dropdown needs it's own fillFunction to be called in the same place, like this, for an example:

```
function LoadBoxFunktionsnedsattning(response) {

         var result = response.d;


         var options = $("#boxFunktionsnedsattning");
         options.text(''); // clear the box content before reloading
         if ($('#boxFunktionsnedsattning').val != '') {
             options.removeAttr("disabled");
             options.multipleSelect("enable");
         }
         else {
             options.attr("disabled", true);
             options.multipleSelect("disable");
         }

         $.each(result, function () {
             options.append($("<option />").val(this.id).text(this.name));

         });
         fillFunktionsnedsattning();
         UpdateBoxEnabledState();
         options.multipleSelect("refresh");
```

It's probably possible to simplify this, but this works for me.